Table over a region
in Mathematica we can easily use SliceVectorPlot3D to create a vector plot over a given region in 3D. For example for some arbitrary field f and an infinite plane defined by the line $y=0,z=0$ and the normal $n = \{0,1/2,1\}$
   f = {#3, -#1 + #2, #1} &;
   SliceVectorPlot3D[f[x, y, z], {y/2 + z == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]

This works great, I want to inspect the field list. So I want to generate a table of the function f on the slice i.e. I want to have a create a table of something like
listonslice = Table[{{x,y,z},{f[x,y,z]}, {y/2 + z == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z,-5, 5}]

Is something like this possible in Mathematica?
Edit: I know that using a mask would probably be possible. We would generate the table in the are box $x \in \langle-5,5 \rangle,y\in \langle-5,5 \rangle, z\in \langle-5,5 \rangle$ and then use the mask. But I want to avoid generating the field in the whole area, because for my application the generation is very slow.

You can use the graphics to get the mean coordinates of the arrows:
Example:
f = {#3, -#1 + #2, #1} &;
svp =SliceVectorPlot3D[f[x, y, z], {y/2 + z == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]

Cases[svp, Arrow[_], Infinity]

points = 
 Cases[svp, Arrow[Tube[{b_, e_}, _]] :> Mean[{b, e}], Infinity]

Graphics3D[Point[points]]
It is also possible to extract the mesh points of your surface if you want more points.

If you're less worried about sampling uniformly, you can also do something like:
reg = ImplicitRegion[ y/2 + z == 0, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}]

Table[
 {pt, f @@ pt},
 {pt, RandomPoint[reg, 100]}
]

